# How to position dynamic content so that other content doesn't move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to set the message after user clicked on the save button. Message should be 'Record has been saved successfully!' Next to the Save button or aligned to the right side of the table. Here is my HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <button type="button" name="save" id="save" onclick="pgSave();">Save</button>
        <span id="msgSave"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("msgSave").innerHTML = "Record has been saved successfully!";
```

Current message will show but Save button will slide to the left. I don't want my button to move once message shows up. Is there any way to fix that? Should I set the standard width or something else is wrong in my HTML.

Comment: `#msgSave { position: absolute }`

Comment: The code you provided doesn't replicate the issue. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwaLpJ Give us a working [mcve] of the current behavior please.

Comment: We can't see the appropriate HTML and CSS to see what is happening but you have a `button` and a `span` aligned centrally in a `td`. If you change the content of the `td` it will move (to remain centered). I would suggest aligning the content to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your table cell will adjust when the content inside it changes! That's the nature of table cells using centered content.

Instead you could do something like:

```
<tr>
  <td width="30%" align="center">
    <button type="button" name="save" id="save" onclick="pgSave();">Save</button>
  </td>
  <td width="30%"><span id="msgSave"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Note that I added widths to the cells - this should keep them the same layout whatever content is in them (more or less).

A better approach would be DIV's though as they don't resize/move like table cells will.

Answer (score 2):

If you align your tr to the left, there will be no slide

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <button type="button" name="save" id="save" onclick="pgSave();">Save</button>
        <span id="msgSave"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know if your layout allows you to align left, but it's an solution

Answer (score 0):

Or inside the same td element put the span enclosed by a p element like this :

<p><span id='msgSave'></span></p>

Since there is a default break for p elements.